# Can someone explain the intuition behind this subsets problem of $P_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this subset of $P_2$ asubspace of $P_2$? 
p(t): p(2) = 0
solution says "yes" for this.

what about this one:
{p(t): p'(1) = p(2)} p' is the derivative.
solution says "yes" for this too.

Comment: Could you define what $P_2$ is? It seems to be some collection of polynomials.

Comment: yup, $P_2$ is just a bunch of polynomials

Comment: Well, then you need to verify that $\lbrace p(t) : p(2)=0 \rbrace$ is closed under addition, scalar multiplication and contains $0$. These should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume $P_2$ is the set of all polynomials of degree at most two, with coefficients in some field.

The nice thing about *alleged* subspaces defined like this is that it's really immaterial if we can even calculate $p'(1)$; the subspace test applies very easily. Call the set of such polynomials $S$.

- Is the $0$ function in $S$? Yes; its derivative is also the $0$ function.
- Is $S$ closed under taking sums? Suppose $p, q \in S$. Then we have $p'(1) = p(2)$ and $q'(1) = q(2)$. Then $(p + q)'(1) = p'(1) + q'(1) = p(2) + q(2)$, by assumption, and that's another way to write $(p + q)(2)$. That's another yes, and finally,
- Is $S$ closed under scalar multiples? Well, given a scalar $\alpha$, we have $(\alpha p)'(1) = \alpha p'(1) = \alpha p(2) = (\alpha p)(2)$.

So, without knowing really anything about what objects in $P_2$ look like, the linearity of the derivative (maybe among other things; it's late) guarantees that $S$ is a subspace.

Of course, if we didn't know better, we could write arbitrary things in $P_2$ as quadratics $p(t) = at^2 + bt + c$ and do all the calculations, but we don't need to!